# Build New Driver - How to Install New Device .inf File

Tags: windows, usb, driver

Forgive my basic questions, firmware guy here. I have been "gifted" ownership of the driver for a HID device. The current driver is outdated in that it no longer supports the full range of USB pids that this product line supports. I have all of the source code, including a simple text file that includes the list of supported PIDs. I added the new range, and executed several Perl scripts with titles like "IncrementVersions", "BuildINFs" and "BuildWindowsDrivers". I can share these scripts if they're helpful.

The upshot is I seem to have some .inf files that were updated correctly: were up-rev'd, and contain the new range of USB PIDs. But if I right click on one and select "Install", I get a message that says "The system cannot find the file specified". Similalrly, if I got into Dev Man and try to update the driver, Dev Man says I'm already using the best driver for that device.

I do notice that previous versions of this driver were built into setup.exe files. I thought I could install an .inf file directly, but perhaps these setup wrappers contain some necessary functionality? How can I create a setup.exe file from an .inf?

Is any of this helpful in pointing me toward what I might be doing wrong? What can I share that would provide more useful info?

Comment: HID devices generally don't need drivers because their USB descriptors specify that they are HID devices, and Windows already has a standard HID driver.  That's why you can plug any keyboard or mouse into Windows and it just works.

Comment: @David Grayson - I understand that Windows has a native HID driver. This particular driver offers functionality beyond what the native HID driver has.

Answer (score 0):

You can install INF files directly but there are three important things to know:

1. The INF file needs a `DefaultInstall` section with a line like "CopyINF=your_inf_name.inf". (Actually I think it's not needed on Windows 10 maybe).
2. You need a `CatalogFile` directive that refers to a `.cat` file in the same directory that you have properly [signed](https://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/) with your code signing certificate.
3. You need to right-click on the INF file in Windows Explorer and click "Install" to actually install it.

Since the system is complaining about a missing file, of course you should also read your INF file carefully and make sure all the files it refers to exist somewhere where Windows knows how to find them.

Comment: thank you so much. I found an earlier build of this driver. For simplicity: for 64-bit Windows, there's a folder containing 6 files: 2 sys files, a .cat file like you mentioned, a .map file, a .pdb file, and finally an .inf file with the same name as my new .inf file. The difference being the older .inf file doesn't include my new PID range. I can't just replace the .inf file with the new one, because then the cat file doesn't have the matching hash. So is my missing step to figure out how to update the .cat file with a hash that's been calculated for my new .inf?

Comment: Yes.  You need to generate a .cat file using Inf2Cat and then also sign it using a proper code signing certificate as installed here, or else you can't install your driver on Windows.  I wrote a lot about this in the link I already posted: https://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/  If the driver is just for internal use, you might look into signing it with your own certificate, or disabling driver signature checking.

Comment: Also, since the original driver packages has SYS files, and those have very strict signature standards, you might consider just installing that package as is, and then you make a new driver package with just a INF file and a signed CAT file, and your new driver package can refer to the SYS files already installed on the system by the old driver package.  It's not elegant but it might be easier than figuring out how to submit drivers to Microsoft and get them signed, which is required to get your SYS files actually loaded into the kernel and running.

Comment: Thanks again. I located the inf2cat tool, but keep getting an error when executing it. Again, for simplicity, I am just trying to get the 64-bit WIN10 version to work. Anything wrong with my syntax? `C:\MT7\bin\7.15\x64\infs\Digitizer>"C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\bin\selfsign\inf2cat" /v /os:10_X64 /driver:.
Operating systems parameter invalid.`

Comment: I don't know exactly what is wrong.  Carefully read the documentation of inf2cat's `os` parameter and maybe try copying verbatim the value I use for that parameter in the article I linked to twice.

Comment: For whatever reason, it appears the tool was expecting a WIN7 os parameter (I suppose because that's when the .inf file was originally written and it makes reference to WIN7). So finally INF2CAT attempts to execute, but after 20-30 seconds of parsing I get a message that "The integrity check for the Windows file protection data file has failed". I may have to punt this down the road; I have no idea how to resolve that.

Comment: Inf2Cat should take less than a second.  I'm not sure what that latest error message is about.